# Did Nathan HaNavi exaggerate the numbers of captains invited?

Tags: sources-mekorot, names, king-david, melachim-kings-book-of, parashat-chaye-sara

Did Nathan HaNavi exaggerate the numbers of captains invited?

In 1 Kings 1:19, Bath-Sheba (under the coaching of Nathan HaNavi) reported to King David that Adonijah invited, among others, "the captain of the host"
(Hebrew, Sar HaTzava; in the singular, שַׂר הַצָּבָא); whereas, a few moments later,
Nathan HaNavi reported to King David, in 1 Kings 1:25, that Adonijahu invited, among others,
"the captains of the host" (Hebrew, Sarey HaTzava, in the plural, שָׂרֵי הַצָּבָא).

Did Nathan HaNavi exaggerate the numbers of captains invited?
Was it a lie? Is there an alternative explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Every army has many generals, but there is usually one supreme commander. In David's army, this was Yoav. Batsheva says that Adoniyahu invited "[Joab commander of the army](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.1.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)", meaning the highest ranking officer. Nathan adds that Adoniyahu invited all of the military officers, which would include Yoav but also lower-ranking generals. So there is no contradiction at all.

---

EDIT: I was asked to show that the word "sar" could also refer to lower-ranking generals. Here is one [source](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.31?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0):

> וַֽיִּקְרְבוּ֙ אֶל־מֹשֶׁ֔ה הַפְּקֻדִ֕ים אֲשֶׁ֖ר לְאַלְפֵ֣י הַצָּבָ֑א שָׂרֵ֥י הָאֲלָפִ֖ים וְשָׂרֵ֥י הַמֵּאֽוֹת׃
> The commanders of the troop divisions, the officers of thousands and the officers of hundreds, approached Moses.

Comment: @n-t it sounds like a good answer, and it could therefore be better if you could show that the plural word "sarey" שָׂרֵי refers also to "lower-ranking generals".

Comment: Aside from your question, what other explanation could there be for having multiple שרים? The only way to have multiple generals is to have a chain of authority; otherwise, they will just contradict each other. This is how every army works.